# [ASP.Net/VB.Net]Retrieving info from a HTML input text block

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, vb.net

I have 2  HTML blocks, with JQuery DateTimePicker. Now after the date is picked (When you click the input box, the datepicker appears, then you click the date, the date appears in the input box, and when you click away somewhere, the datepicker dissapears. Now I need to retrieve that info with VB.Net and ASP.Net.
Thank you.

---

I just changed the HTML input box to Asp.net Textbox
Then added the OnTextChanged function call when the text is changed, and called a function that stores that date into my class. As such:

```
Start date:
<asp:TextBox name="startDate" ID="startDate" OnTextChanged="startDate_TextChanged" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
```

I tried to go with asp:TextBox before, but for some reason JQuery didn't work on it.

Comment: What have you tried? What are you having problems with? We will _not_ do your work for you.

Comment: Is the HTML field marked with `runat="server"`, or are these plain HTML fields?

Comment: It is marked with runat="server", and Oded, I tried Request.Params("startDate"), but that did not work, I think its for form retrieval.

Comment: At the moment I have a HTML input text box, which has a runat="server" attribute, I was wondering, how can I get the value, after it loses its user focus, to retrieve it with vb.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to access the values of the input box on the client side, then you can use jquery as below:

```
         $("#Your_HTML_InputBox_ID").val();
```

On the server side, you can access the values from the FormCollection available on the page you post this form to.

Thanks.

Comment: I need to get it server-side, sorry for not clarifying. 
I am trying to store it in a datetime type to a class.

Comment: You can get the value on the server side only after the form is POSTed back. At this point (on POST back), it will be available in the FormCollection.

Comment: Okay, thank you, I already went a different way, but still helpful :)